# C Basics : Grade Book Using Array Storing and Printing, Plus Looping

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Yes, hello. I'm really new to programming. I genuinely need help because I would like to both understand what I'm doing wrong and also pass my class.

I'm in a Intro to Programming class and my assignment is to create a program that uses an array to store percentage grades in the range from 0 to 100 (inclusive). The program should allow the user to indicate when they are done entering grades. When the user is done entering grades, the program should print out the grades entered.

I have a running code, compiled in Code::Blocks. But my questions/problems are:

A.) What's the best way to tell C when the user is done? Should I

- Leave the code as is and let any key be hit?
- Add a specific variable like 'done'?
- Do something else?

B.) How do I print only the grades that have been entered without it going through all 100 slots? I can't for the life of me find the solution.

Any and all suggestions welcome and appreciated!!!

```
int i = 0;
float percentScore[100];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("Grade %d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%f", &percentScore[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("\n%.2f%%", percentScore[i]);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Should the "print out" be just the grades entered, or should it be the number of grades for each possible percentage (i.e. the count of 100's', the count of 99's, count of 98's... etc.)... ???

Comment: Hi there! The "print out" should be just the grades that were entered.

Comment: Are the number of "grades" known ahead of time...???  If not, then your array for storing the grades will need to be dynamically sized/resized... If the number of grades IS known (or a maximum number of grades is known), then the array can be statically sized.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, the grades are not known ahead of time, it could be any number of them that gets entered before the user says they're done. Thank you! Will look into it.

Comment: Does the question say to limit to 10 inputs? In the input loop you could ask after/before inputtting a grade (your choice but suggest after) _Are you Finished? (Y/N)_ then get Y N. Note just an overview (to do correctly would need more e.g. what if X where input?).

Comment: No, there is no limit to the input--which is why I'm a still a bit unsure how to set the array when I don't know how many inputs the user will add. Ohh...yes, I can see what you're suggesting. Then I could add another variable that's a char and it wouldn't mess up the float variable on my percentScore. Thanks!!!

Comment: You would be amazed at what you can do to terminate input if you simply check the `return` of `scanf` and check for `EOF` or your favorite magic input value, or simply for the first failed input.

Answer (score 1):

Your choices for A) are not mutually exclusive; the first is something the user can do, the second is a way to represent that in the code.  As such, you could reasonably do both.

As for B), you need a way to represent the number of grades entered (hint: a variable); this can then be used to control how many get printed.

Comment: For A), so I could tell the user something like 'Hit 'd' when finished." and add an if statement that if (percentScore == 'd') and then it will print?
 
And for B), okay I'll have to research that and see what I can find. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: percentScore is an array of floats; you can't put a 'd' in it

Comment: Whoops, that is true...I think here's where one of my problems began. Total newbie. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach for your problem:

- for each input, read a full line from the user ;
- try and convert this line as a number with `sscanf()` ;
- if the conversion fails, consider the input exhausted ;
- if the value is out of bounds, restart this input.

The user can thus signal the end of the list by entering a blank line.

Here is a example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GRADE_NB  100

int main(void) {
    int i, n;
    float grade, percentScore[GRADE_NB];
    char buf[100];

    for (n = 0; n < GRADE_NB;) {
        printf("Grade %d: ", n + 1);
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            /* end of file reached: input exhausted */
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(buf, "%f", &grade) != 1) {
            /* not a number: input exhausted */
            break;
        }
        if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
            /* value is OK, grade accepted */
            percentScore[n] = grade;
            n++;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid grade: %f\n", grade);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%.2f%%\n", percentScore[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the potential number of inputs is not limited, you must allocate the array from the heap and reallocate it as more inputs are gathered.  Here is a simple solution for this where the array is reallocated for each input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, n;
    float grade, *percentScore;
    char buf[100];

    for (n = 0, percentScore = NULL;;) {
        printf("Grade %d: ", n + 1);
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            /* end of file reached: input exhausted */
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(buf, "%f", &grade) != 1) {
            /* not a number: input exhausted */
            break;
        }
        if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
            /* value is OK, grade accepted */
            percentScore = realloc(percentScore, (n + 1) * sizeof(*percentScore));
            if (percentScore == NULL) {
                printf("allocation failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
            percentScore[n] = grade;
            n++;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid grade: %f\n", grade);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%.2f%%\n", percentScore[i]);
    }

    free(percentScore);
    return 0;
}
```